# Importing Web MVC app into Forms Desktop Application App.Config Returns Null

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, configuration

We have a windows forms desktop application, we are making a seperate MVC web app that will use the desktop apps business objects. We imported the mvc app as a solution into the desktop solution. The problem is that getting the ConnectionString out of App.Config doesn't seem to work when our startup project is set to the MVC solution. We copied the App.Config file to our MVC websolution, but the statement

```
string remote = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RMSRemoteConnection"];
```

Always loads null. This statment is being called from a class inside the desktop forms application. When our startup project is the Web MVC solution this ConfigManager has problems. We need to use the existing business objects of the main desktop solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> We copied the App.Config file to our MVC websolution

An ASP.NET web application uses `web.config`, not `app.config`. So make sure that you have a `web.config` file in the root of your web application containing this connection string.